# How to search for dialogues in quotation marks and dashes?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to search for dialogues in between quotation marks and dashes, but I can't seem to code it.

Regarding dialogues marked by quotation marks, I have found a way to code it, mainly because that is the way dialogues are composed in English.

Here is my code and it has worked:

```
text = '''
Meneou a cabeça com ar triste e acrescentou:
- O homem acostuma-se a tudo, sim, a tudo, até a esquecer-se que é um homem...
- Ele disse que não sairia -

"Todos vamos ficando diferentes, e vinto e cinco anos é uma vida."

"Para muitos é mais do que isso."

"Claro que é"
'''

direto = re.findall(r'\"([^\"]+?)(\"|\-\-\n)',text)
for d in direto:
    print(d[0])
```

output:

```
"Todos vamos ficando diferentes, e vinto e cinco anos é uma vida.
Para muitos é mais do que isso.
Claro que é"
```

The output is precisely what I wanted. However, when it comes to spotting the dialogues between dashes, I can't seem to find the code. The desired output would have to show the dialogues that appear in between dashes and the ones followed by one dash.

The desired output:

```
"- O homem acostuma-se a tudo, sim, a tudo, até a esquecer-se que é um homem...
- Ele disse que não sairia -
Todos vamos ficando diferentes, e vinto e cinco anos é uma vida.
Para muitos é mais do que isso.
Claro que é"
```

Comment: Can you clarify how _"dialogues that appear in between dashes and the ones followed by one dash."_ gives that desired output? The part from `- O homem` through to `nao sairia -` appears between dashes. The remainder is neither between dashes, nor followed by one.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, You are right, I wasn't very clear. In Portuguese, the language I am working with, dialogues can be marked by either one dash at the beginning of it or two dashes, one at the beginning and one at the end of the sentence. For example: "- o homem (...) que é um homem" is a dialogue as well as "Ele disse que não sairia". Furthermore, in Portuguese, dialogues can also be separated by quotation marks, as in English, but this task has already been done. If I understand it correctly, we need to combine them now. I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To find text in quotation marks, use the pattern `".+"`. It allows all characters in between brackets as long as there is at least one character (that is the `+`).
- To find text starting with a new line and a dash, and ending with a new line character, use: `\s?-\s.+\s`. This assumes any dashes in a text that is followed by a widespace (and optionalle precedet by one) to be a quote.
  You may let it end by a new line or a dash: `(?=\n|(\s-)$)`. the `$` indicates the end of the pattern and the `?=` indicates that regex should look for the new line `\n` but not consume, i.e. print it.
- To look for both patterns at the same run, use the OR condition: `|` (and you will neet to group expressions with brackets`()`

```py
for d in re.finditer(r'(".+")|(-\s.+(?=\n|(\s-))$)', text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(d.group())
```

Yields the output

> - O homem acostuma-se a tudo, sim, a tudo, até a esquecer-se que é um homem...
> - Ele disse que não sairia -
> "Todos vamos ficando diferentes, e vinto e cinco anos é uma vida."
> "Para muitos é mais do que isso."
> "Claro que é"

**edit** don't forget to set the `re.MULTILINE` flag (as I did oO)  otherwise it will only look at the very beginning of the string and not of every line

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for explaining your code. It worked perfectly. If I may still ask something of you, here it is: in Portuguese, words can contain dashes, for example "dê-me", like "give it to me", in English. How can we change your code so that it does not understand "dê-me" as a dialogue. In other words, normally, dialogues appear at the beginning of a sentence, like "- dê-me so". Cheers, pal!

Comment: uh yes, you are righ! If you only want to find dashes right at the beginning of a line, go with a caret: `^-` or (if you are not sure if there is a widespace `^\s?-` and if you are sure that there is always a widespace after the dash, use another `\s` (and make it optional with a question mark: `^\s?-\s?`

Comment: thank you again. I know it is just my lack of experience in Python, but I got confused with your las comment. In fact, I don't know whether there is a widespace or not, as you clearly recognised as an option. So the best thing to do would be to write "^\s?-", isn't it? However, where do I write it inside the re.finditer? Cheers, pal!

Comment: Sorry, I already updated the post right after my comment, so the code should run out of the box. The caret `^` defines that the pattern starts from a new line and `\s` is for widespaces (a space, a tab, or similar) and the `?` says that there is either one or none of whatever was right before it (an asterix `*` would specify none or any number and the plus `+` says there must be at least one occurrence). *regex* is the same in (almost) any language so it might be helpful somewhere else as well =)

Comment: I am sorry, but I could not make it work. Maybe, it is not showing the output I want because I did not formulate my problem properly. I would like to have a code that could find both dialogues like ("Hi there") and dialogues like (- hello, pal). However, we must bear in mind that, in a larger text written in Portuguese, like the one I am working with, I may encounter words with dashes as well, such as "diga-me". These words should not count as dialogues, although they are formed with dashes as well. Therefore,  the code should ignore dashes between words. Thank you very much!

Comment: I forgot to set the `re.MULTILINE` flag which makes the `^` match at the beginning of every new line (and not only the beginning of the entire string). should work now

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! However, something is still odd. When I execute the code, if in my text I have dashes embedded in words ("viu-me", for example), the output shows a just a dash. It was not supposed to show me anything, as it is not a dialogue. I have already done the update that you have provided. Cheers!

Comment: Would you like to extend your example or open another question so I can check? From my point of view, it works nicely also at words like *acostuma-se* or *esquecer-de* from your example. I can't see why it shouln't work for *viu-me*.`regex` is pretty straight forward, perhaps you can already adjust the pattern.  I'm happy to help, but you can also open another question if you have new cases.

Comment: Thank you very much, max. I have just posted another question. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72187713/whey-am-i-getting-a-dash-when-i-try-to-use-regex-on-a-text.  I hope you can help me. Cheers!