# Whey am I getting a dash when I try to use Regex on a text?

Tags: python-3.x

After being helped, I finally managed to apply Regex on a text to try to find some patterns.

My project consists of finding dialogues in a text written in Portuguese. In Portuguese, dialogues can be found in some ways: between dashes (- ele disse que sim-), with a dash starting the dialogue (- ele disse que sim), and in between quotation marks ("eu acho que sim").

However, as words in Portuguese can also contain dashes, such as in "viu-me" or "disse-lhe", I had make a code that takes all of this information into account.

The problem I am having is that I am getting dashes when I search for the pattern in a text.

Here is my code:

```
    text = '''
"Para muitos é mais do que isso."

Eles chegarem em casa são e salvos

Viu-se que eles não estavam lá
'''


 for d in re.finditer(r'(".+")|(^\s?-\s.+\s|-)', text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(d.group())
```

Here is the current output:

```
"Para muitos é mais do que isso."
-
```

Fantastic, the code manages to find the dialogue in quotations, but prints a dash as well. It is as if it found that it is not a dialogue, it is just a word with an embedded dash, but still shows the dash in it.

The desired output:

```
"Para muitos é mais do que isso."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a $ sign at the last of your regex, to denote the end.

```
r'(".+")|(^\s?-\s.+\s|-$)'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That partially worked. When I run the code, however, I still get dashes whenever it finds a word with dashes in a text. The following example was retrieved from a text: "Por sob os seios rijos, protraídos, afinava-se o corpo na cintura para alargar-se em uns quadris amplos". Currently, I am getting a dash for this "afinava-se", but I should not, because it does not mark a dialogue. It is just a dash in the middle of a word, which is pretty normal in Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because in `(^\s?-\s.+\s|-)` the ending with `|-` is incorrect. It basically tells the regex to match `\s?-\s.+\s` OR a dash/hyphen. Which ends up matching the hyphen in `Viu-se`, since there is no notion of spaces in `|-`.

You'll probably also need to remove the `^` in the second group because if there are dashes in the middle of a sentence, you won't catch that.

Examples:

```
import re

text = '''
"Para muitos é mais do que isso."

Eles chegarem em casa são e salvos

Viu-se que eles não estavam lá

hello - More text and example - and stuff

a confusing-example-with-hyphens

Here is something else

- Start with dashes -, "quote me here"
'''

rgx = r'(".+")|(\s?-\s.+\s-)'

for d in re.finditer(rgx, text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(d.group())
```

Gets you:

```sh
"Para muitos é mais do que isso."
 - More text and example -

- Start with dashes -
"quote me here"
```

N.B: You could also control the exact number of spaces you want to see in case you don't want to match on multiple spaces after a dash;
`rgx = r'(".+")|(\s?-\s{1}.+\s{1}-)'`